# iOS6.0 project crashing on iOS5 gestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app created initially in XCode 4.5 with the iOS6 SDK using storyboards. Its deployment target is iOS5.0

It is basically a `tabBarController` with 3 views, one goes to an input screen (and off to another chain of views), one goes to preferences and one goes to a chart.

The chart page consists of a `viewController` (`AdChartViewController`) connected to a custom view (`AdChartView`). It also has a `PinchGesture Recognizer`.

If I run this app in the iPhone 6 simulator it all works fine. If it run it on the iPhone 5.0 simulator, it works fine until I click the tab item for the view, where it crashes in the machine code of `objc_msgsend`. Looking at the stack trace gives me `UINib instatiateWithOwner:Options`, doing a `CFRetain` on a `NSArray`.

If I remove the pinch recognizer, it doesn't crash. When I add it back it does. The `pinchGestureRecognizer` is connected to a action `pinchGestureAction:` which doesn't get called before it crashes on iOS5, and works fine on iOS6.

I see no reason a `pinchRecognizer` shouldn't work on iOS5. Can anyone let me know what I am missing, or where to look next?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue but for me I only get the crash after a memory warning, when the view is being reloaded. Same stack trace though and only iOS 5. Did you find a work around?

Comment: I created a new project and added most of the code back, but restructured the views in the process, after that the crash didn't happen. Not the most helpful I know, but since then I have had no issues.